# Using String to do Math

Tags: java, string, function, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator which allows for multiple operations (e.g. 4+3-2+5). My basic idea for how to do this is by using this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                switch (nums[i]) {
                case add:
                    while (func.size() < i) {
                        func.add(0);
                    }
                    func.add(i, 1);
                    type = "+";
                    break;
                 //More cases for other operations
```

Couple notes: nums.length references an array which contains the input equation split like this: `nums = equation.split("(?<=[-+*/%])|(?=[-+*/%])")`

Ideally, once I have the 'type' value, I'd be able to make my program calculate the equation by doing this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {      
    ans = eq.get(0) type eq.get(func.indexOf(1)+i);
        }
```

Another small note: `eq` is an arraylist with all the values of `nums`.

Pretty much what I want to do is have `type` become math operations like +, -, etc. I know this code is terribly broken in the way I've shown it here, but it's just something I quickly wrote to provide an example of what I want to accomplish. I've looked at other questions similar to this where the solution was to use the `Math` class and call functions from that, but it doesn't work in my program. Anyone have thoughts on a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: If you want to handle operator precedence, you'll need to parse the string in addition to breaking it up into its parts. Google "equation parsing" and you'll find some good suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to use a Syntax directed interpreter rather than an abstract one. I'd highly suggest looking into this, especially if you want your calculator to follow order of operations (which I assume you do). Here's a great example of it:

https://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node24.html

Personally, rather than splitting your input equation by treating the operator as a delimiter, I would think it would be easier to build a constructor with manually specified classes. I would make the full statement expression made up of an operator (string) and integer number arguments to start, and then add on to it as needed. Something like:

```
abstract class Expression {

class Equation extends Expression {
public String operator; //Operator
public Expression left; //Left hand side
public Expression right;//Right hand side
public Equation(String o, Expression l, Expression r) {operator = o, left = l, /n 
right = r}; //Constructor for the Equation
}
```

You can then add on to that to create scenarios for different types of equations. Keep in mind the left hand side, right hand side, and the operator are arbitrary. You could create equations with operators on the left and right as well to allow for multiple operations. Definitely different than how you have this set up, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I'll try this out when I have access to my computer :D